# Pandas Read HTML - Multiple Tables Nested from Published GSheets (Corona Patient DB)

Tags: python, pandas

How to read the table into a pandas dataframe. (Corona Patient Database)

Here is the URL Source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml

[image]

I want to get this data into a dataframe with minimal effort using pandas for further analysis. What is the best way to do it. The HTML is nested with multiple sheets. This is what I have tried so far.

```
url = r'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml'
import pandas as pd
import requests

rtext = requests.get(url).text
```

rtext has all the html with the data. Now I tried Beautiful Soup, but it is very confusing.

Hoping to get a clean solution.

Part of the HTML Table look like this:

```
<table class="waffle" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><thead>
<tr><th class="row-header freezebar-vertical-handle header-shim row-header-shim"></th><th id="0C0" style="width:54px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C1" style="width:60px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C2" style="width:72px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C4" style="width:50px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C5" style="width:48px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C6" style="width:111px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C7" style="width:130px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C8" style="width:201px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C9" style="width:69px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C10" style="width:124px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C11" style="width:190px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C12" style="width:96px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C13" style="width:99px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C14" style="width:99px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C15" style="width:99px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C16" style="width:258px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C17" style="width:96px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C18" style="width:96px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C19" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C20" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C21" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C22" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C23" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C24" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C25" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th><th id="0C26" style="width:100px" class="header-shim"></th></tr></thead><tbody>
<tr style="height:46px;"><th id="0R0" style="height: 46px;" class="row-headers-background row-header-shim"><div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 46px;">1</div></th>
<td class="s0" dir="ltr">Patient Number</td><td class="s1" dir="ltr">State Patient Number</td><td class="s2">Date Announced</td><td class="s2">Age Bracket</td><td class="s0">Gender</td><td class="s0">Detected City</td><td class="s0" dir="ltr">Detected District</td><td class="s2" dir="ltr">Detected State</td><td class="s0" dir="ltr">State code</td><td class="s0" dir="ltr">Current Status</td><td class="s3" dir="ltr">Notes</td><td class="s1" dir="ltr">Contracted from which Patient (Suspected)</td><td class="s2" dir="ltr">Nationality</td><td class="s2" dir="ltr">Type of transmission</td><td class="s2">Status Change Date</td><td class="s3" dir="ltr">Source_1</td><td class="s3" dir="ltr">Source_2</td><td class="s3" dir="ltr">Source_3</td><td class="s1" dir="ltr">Backup Notes</td><td class="s4"></td><td class="s4"></td><td class="s4"></td><td class="s4"></td><td class="s4"></td><td class="s4"></td><td class="s4"></td></tr>
<tr><th style="height:3px" class="freezebar-cell freezebar-horizontal-handle row-header-shim"></th><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td><td class="freezebar-cell"></td></tr>
<tr style="height:20px;"><th id="0R1" style="height: 20px;" class="row-headers-background row-header-shim"><div class="row-header-wrapper" style="line-height: 20px;">2</div></th><td class="s5" dir="ltr">1</td><td class="s6" dir="ltr">KL-TS-P1</td><td class="s5" dir="ltr">30/01/2020</td><td class="s5" dir="ltr">20</td><td class="s6" dir="ltr">F</td><td class="s6" dir="ltr">Thrissur</td><td class="s6" dir="ltr">Thrissur</td><td class="s6" dir="ltr">Kerala</td><td class="s6">KL</td><td class="s6" dir="ltr">Recovered</td><td class="s7" dir="ltr">Travelled from Wuhan</td><td class="s8"></td><td class="s5" dir="ltr">India</td><td class="s5" dir="ltr">Imported</td><td class="s9" dir="ltr">14/02/2020</td><td class="s10" dir="ltr"><a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://twitter.com/vijayanpinarayi/status/1222819465143832577&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1586180154769000&amp;usg=AFQjCNEwtlOETa2v9D30Pjoe-fJxrVA9PA">https://twitter.com/vijayanpinarayi/status/1222819465143832577</a></td><td class="s11" dir="ltr" colspan="2"><a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://weather.com/en-IN/india/news/news/2020-02-14-kerala-defeats-coronavirus-indias-three-covid-19-patients-successfully&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1586180154769000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGWVTymYTvejeSjCqq583NMJ3jbTA">https://weather.com/en-IN/india/news/news/2020-02-14-kerala-defeats-coronavirus-indias-three-covid-19-patients-successfully</a></td><td class="s12 softmerge" dir="ltr"><div class="softmerge-inner" style="width: 198px; left: -1px;">Student from Wuhan</div></td><td class="s13"></td><td class="s13"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the HTML output. If it uses `<table>` markup, look into [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

Comment: @Parfait hi added html table. but you should be able to see the full html in rtext already. it is 5.5MB with multiple sheets so it is very confusing. I think i know how to solve the problem manually to extract cut paste and do it by hand. I don't want to take that long tedious effort if there was easier way using simple techniques. hope someone can simplify.

Comment: @ihightower Did you check out the Google Sheets Python API (GSpread). Here is a quick link for the documentation (https://github.com/burnash/gspread). I think the challenging part would be obtaining OAuth2 credentials, if you have the write or owner access for the data it should be straight forward.

Comment: Did you attempt what I suggested and linked above: `df = pd.read_html(rtext)`?

Comment: pd.read_html(rtext) takes long time to run and just hangs for 10mins+ without a response (still waiting). the html tree is so nested for multiple sheets so it hangs i think. it runs on a fast server. @rohit if i had access to the file, i understand i could export as xls and work on the file directly. the issue is there is no access to the file and we can only access the data through the published html page. this really is the use case. please see if you can read the rtext and parse the table.

Comment: @Parfait finally it finished running, and it returns a list instead of df. df[0] returns the dataframe. and promote header etc. looks like in familiar territory. the only issue then is it was really slow to parse the html. >15 mins i think. i was not watching. any other suggestions. thanks.

Comment: Do you have [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) (the third-party Python XML/HTML library) installed? This is the default *flavor* in `pd.read_html` if installed but reverts to slower `bs4` (or `html5lib`).

Comment: hi i have lxml and i even forced lxml. still no use, it takes 15 minutes for len 13.1Million html text. eventually finished and correct. may be i have to extract the table manually then pass it to lxml? i don't know how, I will see what is easiest and any other ideas will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have my own answer outlined below.

Additional resource: [Parsing HTML Tables in Python](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/parsing-html-tables-in-python-with-pandas/)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import bs4

print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

# get url (published from google sheets, cannot download, only html)
url = r'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml'

# reques read the url and put as text
rtext = requests.get(url).text
print(len(rtext)) #13.9 Million Char

# beautiful soup to identify the number tables
# this is to speed up read_html, otherwise read_html will take 15 mins for 13.9 Million characters to parse
# now it takes < 10 seconds

bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(rtext)
tables = bs.findAll("table") 

# first table is what we want, help to find the table.

t0 = tables[0]

# read_html returns a list of dataframes even for 1 table.
list_df = pd.read_html(str(t0))
list_df

# get dataframe and process
dfindia = list_df[0]
dfindia.columns = dfindia.iloc[0]
dfindia = dfindia.drop([0,1])
dfindia = dfindia.drop(1, axis=1)

dfindia = dfindia[~dfindia['Patient Number'].isna()]
dfindia = dfindia[~dfindia['Date Announced'].isna()]

print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


dfindia
```

Result runs in 14 seconds from download to print in Google Colab

```
2020-04-07 15:16:53
13989044
2020-04-07 15:17:07
```

[image]